# "Can cities shape socio-technical transitions and how would we know if they were?" were or could?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

> [Can cities shape socio-technical transitions and how would we know if they were?](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S004873331000034X)

This is the title of a peer-reviewed article in the journal "Research Policy". Is it correct? My expectation is that *can* should be matched by *could*, and not *were*.

Comment: Your basic premise of *can* -> *could* is correct, but only if you're staying in the same 'band of meaning'; the title is asking two questions: *can cities shape socio-technical transitions?* and *how would we know if they were shaping social-technical transitions?*.

Comment: How can this not be grammar? And ELL?? how would we know if there [were being shaped by them].

Comment: What is your actual problem? Are you the author of the article?

Comment: @MetaEd - I'm pretty sure what happened was that OP came across this title, thought s/he detected a problem but felt a bit doubtful, and came here to ask the opinion of experts.

Comment: I misread the question itself, however, and deleted my answer.  My current view: "Could."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don’t think you’ll get a right or wrong here, just degrees of acceptability to native speakers.  There are other possibilities besides the two you’ve mentioned, too.

- Can cities shape socio-technical transitions and how would we know if they **were**?
- Can cities shape socio-technical transitions and how would we know if they **could**?
- Can cities shape socio-technical transitions and how would we know if they **had been**?

It might help to try to complete that presumed ellipsis there.

- Can cities shape socio-technical transitions and how would we know if they **were *doing so***?
- Can cities shape socio-technical transitions and how would we know if they **could *be* (*shaped that way*)**?
- Can cities shape socio-technical transitions and how would we know if they **had been (*shaped that way*)**?

The choice of verb seems to govern what elliptical possibilities exist.

Comment: can + were [being shaped by it] is the most obvious reading